# Yosemite: Change keyboard layout of an input source

Tags: keyboard, macos, input-source

My MBP has an AZERTY keyboard (a French keyboard, more precisely). I usually type English, French and Vietnamese. For the latter I use the built-in Vietnamese Telex input source. Since I'm used to type Vietnamese on QWERTY keyboards, I want to change the layout of this input source to QWERTY as well, but I didn't figure out how to do that.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just switch your keyboard to the US layout before you switch to Telex.  It takes the layout of the last keyboard used.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is very helpful, I've learned something :D But I hope there is a better solution.

Comment: I don't think you will find another one.  That is how this IM and all the ones for Chinese are designed to work.  Only the Japanese IM lets you set the layout permanently.

Comment: @Tomg: sorry for the late reply, because I didn't receive any notification for your comment (please tag the person when you reply to his/her comment). 
If there's no other options, then your answer solved my problem :D Thanks.